# Prove a complex function involving modulus is surjective.

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I would like to prove:

$h: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
\\
h = |z| - z$

is surjective.

That is, for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$, I would like to find some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $g(z) = w$

I would normally solve the equation $w = |z| - z$ for z, however I can't seem to make any progress.

I have tried using $z\overline{z} = |z|^2$ but it does not seem to lead anywhere.

Some suggestions on what I might try would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe solve $h(x+iy)=u+iv$ to determine, for any values of $u$ and $v$, if there are specific values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Hint: start with $z=|z|-w$, take conjugates $\bar z = |z| - \bar w$, then multiply the two.

Comment: @dxiv When you say multiply the two, what do you mean? 
I have tried multiplying by z, but got stuck. Also tried squaring but no progress.

Comment: Multiply the two equalities $\,z \bar z = \left(|z|-w\right)\left(|z|-\bar w\right)\,$. Expand, cancel out, and pay close attention to what's left.

Comment: @dxiv So we get left with $|z| = \frac{|w|^2}{w+\overline{w}}$. Not sure if we can we can take this any further. The answer below states this function as no surjective, so is that supposed to be evident from this equation? Thanks.

Comment: You can only divide if $w+\bar w \ne 0$ but you don't know that. The safe way to write it is $|z| \cdot 2 \text{Re}(w)=|w|^2$. If $\text{Re}(w) \lt 0$ there are no solutions since the RHS is positive. If $\text{Re}(w)=0$ there are again no solutions unless $w=0$. Finally, if $\text{Re}(w) \gt 0$ then there is a unique solution $|z|=\frac{|w|^2}{2\text{Re}(w)}$ $\implies z=|z|-w$ $=\frac{|w|^2}{2\text{Re}(w)}-w$ $=\frac{-w^2}{2\text{Re}(w)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$h(z)=|z|-z$ is definitely NOT surjective as for example its image avoids the negative numbers since if $|z|-z=-a, a>0$ one gets $z=a+|z|$ and obviously that is absurd since then $z>0$ and $z=a+z$, so $a=0$

Note that $1-e^{i\theta}=2\sin \frac{\theta}{2} e^{i(\theta-\pi)/2}$ so if $w=|w|e^{i\alpha} \ne 0$, one needs to find $r>0, 0 \le \theta <2\pi$ st $2r\sin \frac{\theta}{2}=|w|$ and $\theta-\pi=2\alpha$ so one gets restrictions on $\arg w$ for which one can solve this equation (namely $\arg w \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ as $\theta=0$ forces $w=0$)

So for all $w \ne 0, \arg w \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ one can solve uniquely $\theta-\pi=2\alpha$ with $\theta \ne 0$ so one can find $r=|w|/(2\sin \frac{\theta}{2})$

For $w=0$ obviously all $z \ge 0$ work

Comment: So your first paragraph is proof that the function is not surjective. I'm not sure I follow the rest of your answer. What are you proving there? Thanks.

Comment: the fact  that the image of $h$ consists of $w \ne 0, \arg w \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and $0$ with the set $w \ne 0, \arg w \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ having a unique preimage

Comment: Why can we assume $z > 0$ in the first paragraph? What if $z < 0$ provide a solution?

Comment: I see now. Because if $z < 0$, $|z| - z > 0$.